# radio button checked causes enabling of a textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

i have a 2 radio buttons that belong to the same group.
asp net radio buttons not regular input type radio buttons.

if the first radio button is selected, the textbox beside it will be enabled. else it will be disabled.
i have seen that for input type radio buttons using JQUERY. so far i wasnt able to adapt that code to my asp.net controls.

i need it 2 be javascript and not in code behind.

any advice?

thanks!

here is my code

```
    <table>
<tr>
   <td>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="SiteLicenseRBN" runat="server" Checked="True"   
                                    GroupName="users" resourcekey="SiteLicenseRBN" 
                                    Text="Site License" TextAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="ConcUsersRBN" runat="server" GroupName="users"
                                    Text="Conc. Users" TextAlign="Left" 
                                    resourcekey="ConcUsersRBN" Font-Bold="True" 
                                   />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="nuserstbx" runat="server" Enabled="False"
                                    Width="71px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if the 2nd radio button is selected(Conc. Users), then nuserstbx must be enabled, else it should be disabled.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit of your markup and maybe what you have tried to adapt the code you found

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<form name="myform">
 <input type="radio" name="radios" onclick="rtest(this)" value="R1"/>
 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="t1"/>

 <input type="radio" name="radios" onclick="rtest(this)" value="R2"/>
 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="t2"/>

 <input type="radio" name="radios" onclick="rtest(this)" value="R3"/>
 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="t3"/>
</form>

<script>
 function rtest(r){
    var allinputs = document.myform.elements;
    for(var i=0; i < allinputs.length; i += 1 ){
        if ( allinputs[i].type === "text" ){
           if ( allinputs[i].previousElementSibling.checked ){
               allinputs[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
           }else{
               allinputs[i].disabled = "disabled";
           }
       }
    }
 }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HjLeH/

Answer (score 0):

This a quick basic example. All textboxes are disabled. But when you click on the first radio button it will make the texbox beside it active.

**HTML**

```
 <span id="radiobutt">
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" id="textbox1" disabled="disabled"/>
    <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="2" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" disabled="disabled"/>
    <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="3" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" disabled="disabled"/>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $$("#radiobutt input[type=radio]").each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function () {
        if(i==0) {
                $("#textbox1").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#checkbox1").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
                $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#checkbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      });
  });
```

Or you can view the working example here

http://jsfiddle.net/fqueT/1/

Comment: i already know this and thanks! i need it for asp.net controls not simple input type radio button. i need it 2 work for ASP:RadioButton

Comment: @Ghassan Asp:RadioButtons are rendered on the browser exactly like simple input type radio buttons. Yes the framework might give them different ids but they will still be in the form of <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="3" />